# Matrix3DProjection exists in Silverlight but not in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, matrix, transform

I need a taper-effect on my transform in WPF.
Charles Petzold wrote some nice stuff about it for example :
http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/07/Using-the-Matrix3DProjection-Class-in-Silverlight-3.html

But now it seems that the used Matrix3DProjection class only exists in Silverlight, and NOT in WPF..?
(Why would Mirosoft think it could only be useful in Silverlight and not in WPF ?)

Is there any way to get around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix3DProjection is in Silverlight because Silverlight doesn't have full 3D support like WPF has.

You can do everything by using the 3D support.

Yes, Matrix3DProjection is easy and "real" 3D is really difficult and I personally struggled to do something in 3D that would have been easy with Matrix3DProjects and I hope Matrix3DProjection will make it into a future version of WPF - but now that you know the reason don't you feel better? (I don't)